# How did Rita know she lost the power?

Tags: time-travel, edge-of-tomorrow

In *Edge of Tomorrow*, Emily Blunt's character, Rita Vrataski, had the time-resetting power previously.  She details the backstory of how she gained it, and how she lost it.  However, how did she know when she lost the power?  It's only triggered when the wielder dies.

Obviously she didn't die after losing the power, so how did she know the power was gone?

Comment: Wasn’t there something about getting visions of the location of the Omega? Presumably she stopped getting those after she lost the reset ability, so it might act as an indicator.

Comment: @alexwlchan As presented to us during the film, Cage received those during his time loop resets.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### She didn't have to die to be aware of having lost the ability.

- After waking in the field hospital and having had a transfusion, she said she could feel that she had lost the power. She also no longer had the visions which indicated a primary connection to the Omega mind.
- Cage says the same thing once he wakes in the hospital. He said he could feel the loss of the power, a lack of connection to the alien hive-mind.